# How to merge bitstrings JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, merge

I have this `ArrayList<Arraylist>`
    clusters: `[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0]]`

For each of the bitStrings (inner arrayList) the entropy is calculated and produce as follows:

```
inner index #0 : [1, 0, 0, 0] = 0.811
inner index #1 : [0, 0, 0, 0] = 0
inner index #2 : [0, 0, 0, 0] = 0
inner index #3 : [0, 0, 1, 1] = 1
inner index #4 : [1, 1, 1, 0] = 0.811
```

The calculation for entropy is as follows:
for **inner index #0**:

Probability of 0 is 3/4=0.75 and Probability of 1 is 1/4=0.25.
Then, entropy = -((0.75)*(log(0.75)/log(2)) + (0.25)*(log(0.25)/log(2))) = 0.811

Then, after obtaining the entropy for all the bits I would like to merge the two like the following:

Lets say #0 and #1 so the bits will become:

```
**Before merge**
inner index #0 : [1,0,0,0]  
inner index #1 : [0,0,0,0]  

**After merge**  
inner index #0 and #1 : [ [1,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0] ]
```

Then after the merge I will find probability of `[0,0]`, `[0,1]`, `[1,0]` and `[1,0]` (for possible permutation) existed to calculate the entropy again. So in the case above:

```
P([0,0]) = 3/4 = 0.75 (because there are 3 [0,0] in outer array of 4)  
P([0,1]) = 0/4 = 0  
P([1,0]) = 1/4 = 0.25 (because there are 1 [1,0] in outer array of 4)    
P([1,1]) = 0/4 = 0
```

Then the same way to calculate entropy is applied.

After #0 and #1 is merged, let's say I want to merge the #0 and #1 with #3 so it'll produce as follows:

```
**Before merge**  
#0 and #1 : [ [1,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0] ]  
#3 : [0, 0, 1, 1]  

**After merge**  
#0, #1, #3 : [ [1,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,1] ]
```

then the probability of all possible permutations `[0,0,0]`, ...., `[1,1,1]` will be calculated and repeat calculating the entropy.

Therefore, how can I code it in java to find the probability in a flexible way because the bits can be longer and the permutation pattern to find the probability might be longer?

Comment: You could first try and apply your reasonings literally and see what you end up with. Also, have you ever considered using `BitSet` since all you seem to use are 0s or 1s?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I've tried but it only works for the first one and not sure how to merge it and calculate the probability when merged:

```
public static double calculateEntropy(ArrayList<Integer> bitSet){
     double entropy = 0.0;
     double P_C0,P_C1;
     int C0_count = 0, C1_count = 0;
     int bitSize = bitSet.size();

    System.out.println("bitSet to calculate: " + bitSet);
    System.out.println("bitSize = " + bitSize);

    for (int k = 0 ; k < bitSize; k++){
        if (bitSet.get(k) == 0)
            C0_count++;
        else if (bitSet.get(k) == 1)
            C1_count++;
    }

    System.out.println("CO: " + C0_count);
    System.out.println("C1: " + C1_count);

    P_C0 = (double)C0_count/bitSize;
    P_C1 = (double)C1_count/bitSize;

    System.out.println("P_C0: " + P_C0);
    System.out.println("P_C1: " + P_C1);

    entropy = -( (P_C0*(Math.log(P_C0)/Math.log(2))) + (P_C1*(Math.log(P_C1)/Math.log(2))) );

    if(Double.isNaN(entropy)){
        entropy = (double)0.00;

    }

    return entropy;
}
```

Comment: OP didn't show any attempt at solving its own question. This site is not aimed at making other people homework. Please do not answer such questions with ready-to-run code.